# importing multiple contacts into tableview from iphone

Tags: iphone

i am able to import contacts from phone contacts to a table in my application directly and one by one also...
but i want to add multiple contacts from phone contacts to my table view.

can any one please help me how to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this by creating a custom UITableViewController.

- Get all the contacts from the addressbook, then populate tableview cells.
- In "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method, add a check mark to the cell, and add it to an array to hold selections.
- When done, call delegate and pass the array of selected people to it.

Comment: as far as i know, yes.  ABaddressbook framework provided viewcontrollers do not allow multi-selection, so you have to do your own.